# Why does my bootstrap Stylesheet opens as html, not css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to apply a bootstrap theme to my webpage in my development (local) server on my Windows 8 system. I am using Chrome and in Chrome Dev Tools, the stylesheet (css)loads.

However, the bootstrap-theme stylesheet is not applying to the html. The problem was "Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with mime type text/html".

I saw that when i attempted to open the stylesheet from view page source link, it opens as html, not css.However, the bootstrap file is saved with .css extension. I have tried several solutions suggested on stackoverflow, however none of them solved the problem.

Among the solutions i tried:

- Add type="text/css" to the link to the css file. Although I believe in HTML5, we don't need to specify that.
- On IIS (Internet Information Services),enable static content.
- Edit the Registry key to "text/css" at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.
- Add mimetype in settings.py file

But none of them worked. Can you please suggest solutions to my question? Thank you.
I think the relevant css and javascript code is the following. I have tried with and without '/' before the css folder.

Theme Template for Bootstrap

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="{% static 'css/theme.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

>  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
>     <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>
>     <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"><\/script>')</script>
>     <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
>     <script src="{% static 'js/docs.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the CDN instead:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: The CDN worked, but why does the local copy not work. Any reason?

Comment: I'm not sure - I have never seen "{% static" syntax before in a link tag. Googling reveals that its Django syntax - is that what you are using?

Comment: Yes, You are right. I am using Django 1.11. I was able to see it work before with "{% static %}" syntax which is the path for the static directory.

Comment: Its probably down to the configuration of that static folder in Django then. Which is out of my depth unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the bootstrap file is saved with the `.css` file extension and served with a correct mime-type (i.e: `text/css`)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because of not appropriately defining the static directory in settings.py. I needed to update the settings.py for static folder as : STATIC_URL='/static/' and set STATIC_ROOT.